# How to protect password while use paramiko module make ssh connection in python scripts?

Tags: python, linux, bash

Now my way is embedded python code in bash script ,like :

```
#!/bin/bash

python <<EOF 
print "${1}"
EOF
```

and then encrypt it with shc ( http://www.datsi.fi.upm.es/~frosal/ ).
any better way ?

Answer (score 1):

I keep passwords in ~/.netrc and use the Python netrc module to fetch them based on the hostname.